# React Native - TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating' t.preventAutoHide')

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I have a problem exporting my application written in React Native to a working apk file.
I use `gradlew assembleDebug` for export, the command itself works and the apk is created in the folder `android \ app \ build \ outputs \ apk \ debug` but after installation on the phone / emulator there is an error as in the screenshot

[screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Ert.png)

the application launched in yarn start (expo) works without errors

Versions of my packages

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-devtools": "3.6.3",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-gradient-buttons": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-netinfo": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-unimodules": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
```

Java jdk-14.0.1
Gradle 4.10.1

Comment: To make it easier to help you, can you create a minimal reproducible example (maybe a GitHub repo)? To do this, remove as much code from your app as is possible while still causing the error. As is, this is quite hard to answer, from just the error message.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't add the code, but I created a new application via CLI instead of expo, I transferred the code of my application there and everything started working